# Cloudstack doesn't detect/add secondary NFS storage

Tags: cloudstack

My goal is to setup the secondary storage and the nfs server on the same machine as the management server. I've followed the guidelines according to the cloudstack installation docs [here](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-installation/en/4.9/management-server/index.html#using-the-management-server-as-the-nfs-server) but the secondary storage is still not configured, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spahD.png)

The main goal of adding NFS storage is so that the SSVM can run, and thus enabling me to download ISO images to create instances.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the nfs storage is working properly and you are able to mount it on Hypervisor.

```
mount -t nfs management-server-ip:/nfsshare /mnt
```

If this is working properly then you can add this nfs share as secondary storage.

Once secondary storage has been added make sure you register system vm template.
Mount the nfs share on management server itself and register the template:

```
mount -t nfs management-server-ip:/nfsshare /mnt

/usr/share/cloudstack-common/scripts/storage/secondary/cloud-install-sys-tmplt \
-m /mnt/secondary \
-u http://cloudstack.apt-get.eu/systemvm/4.6/systemvm64template-4.6.0-kvm.qcow2.bz2 \
-h kvm -s <optional-management-server-secret-key> -F
```

Download the template as per your hypervisor and then enable the zone.
After this ssvm should work fine.

I hope this helps.